# How to stop reload page after navigation windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

My mainpage call to Page1. I add a webbrowser control to the Page1. When the webbrowser load data complate, I go the background.Then, i back my Page1, webbrowser reload data. How to stop reload it?

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        _mlink = NavigationContext.QueryString["link"];
        web.Navigate(new Uri(_mlink, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`NavigationEventArgs.NavigationMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs.navigationmode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to determine which direction the navigation is coming from.

The available options can be found [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationmode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but listed out, they are:

- New
- Back
- Forward
- Refresh

So my tip would be to determine which value of this you want to navigate the web browser control on (I would guess `New`).

Answer (score 0):

NavigationEventArgs.NavigationMode  works only in windows phone 8.  So edit the code like this.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        _mlink = NavigationContext.QueryString["link"];
        if(web.Source.AbsolutePath!=_mlink)
             web.Navigate(new Uri(_mlink, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```